# Shopify insert content every nth paragraph

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have this code in my liquid file:

```
{% assign beatles = article.content | split: "</p>" %}
{% for member in beatles %}
  {{ member }}
{% endfor %}
```

What I am trying to do is insert content every 2nd, 4th, 6th paragraph.

How do I do this, I understand I can get content from the array using {{ member[2] }} for example, but how do I then insert content after this paragraph?

Comment: You want to insert the content only  at 2,4 and 6th place or the consecutive even numbers like 2,4,6,8,10.....

Comment: @LakshayKalra insert the content only at 2,4 and 6th place

Answer (score 0):

Found out a way to do this. Within the for loop I needed to add

```
{% if forloop.index == 2 %}
    <p>PARA 2</p>
{% endif %}
{% if forloop.index == 4 %}
    <p>PARA 4</p>
{% endif %}
```

etc. Hope that helps others.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helps:

```
{%- assign modulo = forloop.index | modulo: 2 -%}
{% if modulo == 0 and forloop.index <= 6 %}
  <p>PARA  {{ forloop.index }}</p>
{%- endif -%}
```